# WinRT - how to open file in code and prevent users from trying to open files of the same type with app

Tags: windows-runtime, storagefile

In my WinRT app I need to read a specific text file from the users documents folder (I know exactly where the file is because the WinRT app is a companion to software the user has already installed). I can do this with StorageFile/ReadTextAsync and a registered file association type added to the app manifest.

My problem is that since I must declare a File Association in the app manifest, now every time a user opens ANY text file (.txt) Windows 8 alerts them that my WinRT app can open it. This is not ideal because my app is only programmatically reading a specific text file at one place in code - it cannot open ANY text file. Of course if I remove the file association from the manifest then I am unable to read my text file programmatically.

My question is how can I read a text file in code, but not enable  users to think my app can open any text file?

Note: There is a checkbox on the file association properties called "Always Unsafe" which you'd think would do what I want, but apparently it does not disable users from being able to open text files with my app.

Comment: Instead of using a file association, have you considered having your "companion desktop app" ACL the file so that your app can read it without user permission?  E.g., you can grant ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES access to the file, which would grant all apps access to the file.  I would suspect that there is a way to grant access only to a particular app, though I don't know for sure.

Comment: You might be on to something but I haven't found any proof that WinRT apps will open a file that has been given special permissions without a file type association required. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might have understood your situation wrong, but if within your app the user can chose a file, you can filter what type of files he can open at the picker options.

Comment: In this situation the user is not choosing a file. They run the WinRT app and the app reads a specific txt file found in their documents directory. Actually, it reads many text files that are installed to their documents directory by another piece of software. - Thanks